# Color a row based on condition in Interactive report in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I wanted to color the complete row based on some criteria. My query looks like this:

```
select QUIZ_ID,
       QUIZ_NAME,
       QUIZ_TOTAL_SCORE,
       QUIZ_MINIMUM_SCORE,
       START_DATE,
       END_DATE,
       ACTIVE_FLAG      
from QUIZ;
```

When the `ACTIVE_FLAG` value = 'Y' then I want the row to be colored. I have used a technique which I found somewhere but it is not what I am looking for. It has colored the text not complete cell (shown below). But I want complete cell to be colored.

[image]

Comment: Interactive report?

Comment: Hi Diganta, did you find a way to colour the whole cell rather than just the text? I've got the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Interactive Report instead of classic report, you have that ability via the "Actions" button/menu, "Format" option,  "Highlight" option, where you can enter your criteria and what colors you want for foreground (text), and background, and whether to highlight the cell or whole row.

[image: Sample criteria]